# Setup Intershop 7.10 Development environment

Tags: intershop

Folks,

Can you please help me with below error coming when executing 
gradlew clean eHCR publish

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'D:\Projects\xxx\xxx_project\xxx_assembly\build.gradle' line: 15
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':xxx_assembly'.

  > Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':xxx_assembly:com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x'.
  >   Could not find com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x:7.10.3.1.
  >    Required by:
  >        com.xxx:xxx_assembly:1.0.0-LOCAL
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Build.gradle:

```
inheritFrom('com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x') 
{
    includeArtifacts type:['deploy-settings-gradle']
}
```

Please help.

```
Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':xxx_assembly'.
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl$2.run(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:150)
        at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:72)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:155)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:38)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:25)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:34)
        at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:55)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:521)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.AbstractProject.evaluate(AbstractProject.java:92)
        at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:47)
        at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultBuildConfigurer.configure(DefaultBuildConfigurer.java:35)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$2.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:125)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:52)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:122)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.access$200(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:32)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:99)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
        at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ExecuteBuildActionRunner.run(ExecuteBuildActionRunner.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonUsageSuggestingBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:43)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:170)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:61)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.artifacts.ResolveException: Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':xxx_assembly:com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultLenientConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultLenientConfiguration.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.rethrowFailure(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:36)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultResolvedConfiguration.getFirstLevelModuleDependencies(DefaultResolvedConfiguration.java:49)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver$FilesAggregatingResolvedConfiguration.getFirstLevelModuleDependencies(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:96)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver$ErrorHandlingResolvedConfiguration.getFirstLevelModuleDependencies(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:205)
        at com.intershop.common.artifacts.DependencyUtils.resolveSingleModule(DependencyUtils.groovy:252)
        at com.intershop.common.artifacts.DependencyUtils.resolveSingleModule(DependencyUtils.groovy:243)
        at com.intershop.build.assembly.inheritance.AssemblyInheritanceUtil.getAssemblyId(AssemblyInheritanceUtil.groovy:25)
        at com.intershop.build.assembly.inheritance.AssemblyInheritanceUtil.getInheritedAssemblyIvyFile(AssemblyInheritanceUtil.groovy:37)
        at com.intershop.build.assembly.hosttype.InheritedHostTypeProvider.provideSubsets(InheritedHostTypeProvider.groovy:36)
        at com.intershop.build.gradle.plugins.AssemblyExtension$_inheritFrom_closure12.doCall(AssemblyExtension.groovy:286)
        at com.intershop.build.gradle.plugins.AssemblyExtension.inheritFrom(AssemblyExtension.groovy:285)
        at build_2cfc7pnzhx1qg72j39nnpeszf$_run_closure1.doCall(D:\Projects\b2x710\xxx_project\xxx_assembly\build.gradle:15)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.ClosureBackedAction.execute(ClosureBackedAction.java:67)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage$ExtensionHolder.configure(ExtensionsStorage.java:145)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.ExtensionsStorage.configureExtension(ExtensionsStorage.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultConvention$ExtensionsDynamicObject.invokeMethod(DefaultConvention.java:207)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.CompositeDynamicObject.invokeMethod(CompositeDynamicObject.java:150)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.BasicScript.methodMissing(BasicScript.java:79)
        at build_2cfc7pnzhx1qg72j39nnpeszf.run(D:\Projects\b2x710\xxx_project\xxx_assembly\build.gradle:14)
        at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
        ... 50 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.resolve.ModuleVersionNotFoundException: Could not find com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x:7.10.3.1.
Required by:
    com.xxx:xxx_assembly:1.0.0-LOCAL
        at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableComponentResolveResult.java:38)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolveModule(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.resolve(RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver.java:59)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ComponentMetaDataResolverChain.resolve(ComponentResolversChain.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.clientmodule.ClientModuleResolver.resolve(ClientModuleResolver.java:44)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:560)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$ModuleVersionResolveState.getMetaData(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:570)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.calculateTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:256)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder$DependencyEdge.attachToTargetConfigurations(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:230)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.traverseGraph(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.graph.DependencyGraphBuilder.resolve(DependencyGraphBuilder.java:75)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:88)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
        at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactDependencyResolver.java:78)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:41)
        at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
        at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultConfigurationResolver.resolve(DefaultConfigurationResolver.java:91)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyConfigurationResolver.java:40)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.resolve(ShortCircuitEmptyConfigurationResolver.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingConfigurationResolver.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveGraphIfRequired(DefaultConfiguration.java:367)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.resolveNow(DefaultConfiguration.java:342)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration.getResolvedConfiguration(DefaultConfiguration.java:335)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.configurations.DefaultConfiguration_Decorated.getResolvedConfiguration(Unknown Source)
        at com.intershop.common.artifacts.DependencyUtils$_resolveSingleModule_closure13.doCall(DependencyUtils.groovy:249)
        at com.intershop.common.artifacts.DependencyUtils$_resolveSingleModule_closure13.call(DependencyUtils.groovy)
        at com.intershop.common.artifacts.DependencyUtils.withTemporaryConfiguration(DependencyUtils.groovy:320)
        at com.intershop.common.artifacts.DependencyUtils.withTemporaryConfiguration(DependencyUtils.groovy:294)
        at com.intershop.common.artifacts.DependencyUtils.withTemporaryConfiguration(DependencyUtils.groovy:288)
        at com.intershop.common.artifacts.DependencyUtils.resolveSingleModule(DependencyUtils.groovy:248)
        ... 65 more
```

Also, I am getting below warning messages while I do gradlew clean eHCR publish

```
This project is not included in a SCM!
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration2'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration3'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration4'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration5'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration6'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration7'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration8'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration9'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration10'.).
Download https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components/com/github/groovy-wslite/groovy-wslite/1.1.3/groovy-wslite-1.1.3.pom
Download https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.6/groovy-all-1.7.6.pom
Download https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components/com/github/groovy-wslite/groovy-wslite/1.1.3/groovy-wslite-1.1.3.jar
Download https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.6/groovy-all-1.7.6.jar
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration11'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration12'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration13'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration14'.).
```

Comment: How about running the command with `--stacktrace` to actually find out why `com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x` hasn't been found. And post the beginning of the stacktrace here. The error you posted could mean anything.

Comment: with stacktrace added.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid your question is to general to get a simple answer. It could be anything from access permissions to Intershop's bin repository itself, or insufficient license rights for B2X, or...

I suggest you ask Intershop Support for help.

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks for your answer. Nexus has been set up fine as with same Nexus, I am able to configure 7.9. Not sure what changes needs to be done for 7.10. I have just changes version number to 7.10.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Highly likely that the artifact repository server isn't setup correctly. If you followed the [CI setup kb](https://support.intershop.com/kb/index.php/Display/279D85) with nexus then u can test it by opening this link in your browser with your nexus hostname:

```
https://<host>/nexus/content/repositories/ishrepo/com.intershop.assembly/commerce_management_b2x/7.10.3.1/
```

You should see the folders: gradle,ivy,zips,dmps

Comment: Hi Willem, thanks for your answer. I have checked the repository and mentioned URL and working. I am however, not able to see dmps folder but gradle, ivy, zips can be seen. Any other possibility, please share.

Comment: can you see the this file : /nexus/content/repositories/ishrepo/com.intershop.assembly/commerce_management_b2x/7.10.3.1/ivys/ivy-7.10.3.1.xml

Comment: Hi @Willem, Yes, I can see that & access it as well.

Comment: Repository seems fine then. Can start a new 7.10  proj by downloading the demo store? It might be that u are missing some gradle plugins.

Comment: Hi @Willem, How can i download the demo store ?

Comment: Hi @Willem, I just downloaded the latest version of a_responsive and then this issue is not coming anymore. However, I am getting a new issue, which i will be creating in a new thread. Closing this ticket for now. Thanks for your help.