# Intershop 7.10 : Warning Message during publishing Build

Tags: intershop

What is the meaning of below message

```
Defaults for xx.com.intershop are used for inject repositories!
The local artifacts are stored in D:\Projects\b2x710\.gradle\.localRepo!
Repository 'ivyComponents' with url 'https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components' removed from project ':'. Only repositories on 'ci.intershop.com.xx,nexus.intershop.com.xx' are allowed.

This project is not included in a SCM!
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration1'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration2'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration3'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration4'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration5'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration6'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration7'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration8'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration9'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration10'.).
Download https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components/com/github/groovy-wslite/groovy-wslite/1.1.3/groovy-wslite-1.1.3.pom
Download https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.6/groovy-all-1.7.6.pom
Download https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components/com/github/groovy-wslite/groovy-wslite/1.1.3/groovy-wslite-1.1.3.jar
Download https://<nexushost>/nexus/content/groups/components/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy-all/1.7.6/groovy-all-1.7.6.jar
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration11'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration12'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.assembly:commerce_management_b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration13'.).
It was not possible to create stream from com.intershop.responsive:inspired-b2x input (Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration 'detachedConfiguration14'.).
```

What could be wrong ?

Comment: can you add more details, what cmd are u running?

Comment: Also this seems to be related to your other question, maybe close this one and add this info to the previous question

Comment: Ok, will close this one..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setup Intershop 7.10 Development environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54674619/setup-intershop-7-10-development-environment)